# matplotlib navigation toolbar edit curves and parameters line color automatically changes issue

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, navigation, pyside

Let's consider an axis has multiple lines with colors such as blue, green, yellow, red, magenta, cyan etc. When user just selects any curve and just presses ok without changing anything, then automatically yellow and green colors are changed with a slight difference.

This happens only with yellow, green colors.

```
    import sys
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
    matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PySide'
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import PySide
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

    class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

            self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
            self.fig = Figure((5.0, 4.0), dpi=100)
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

            vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
            vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)  # the matplotlib canvas
            vbox.addWidget(self.toolbar)
            self.widget.setLayout(vbox)
            self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

            self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
            X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256, endpoint=True)
            C, S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)

            self.axes.plot(X, C,  linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-", label="cosine")

            self.axes.plot(X, S,  linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-", label="sine")
            self.axes.legend()
            self.canvas.draw()
    def main():
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        form = MyApp()
        form.show()
        app.exec_()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Now run this script and click on Edit Curves and axes parameters button of toolbar and click OK without any changes. We can notice green color changing. The same happens with Yellow color also.

Thanks,
Haney.

Comment: Post some code example, so we can help you better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide some code for us to help you with? Without any code or further information from you, this question is rather **unclear** and is at risk of being closed.

Comment: @phyrox  Thanks for your reply. I edit my post with sample code.